# ReferenceError: getCalendarByName is not defined

Tags: calendar

What am I doing wrong that I get this error ReferenceError: getCalendarByName is not defined

```
`function create_Events(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:J" + lastRow).getValues();



  for(var i = 0;i< data.length;i++){



    if (data[i][0] == 'On Loan' && data[i][1] && data[i][4] && data[i][9])
    {
  
  
    var event = getCalendarByName('Science Lending Library Example')[0].createEvent(data[i][9],
    new Date(data[i][1]),
    new Date(data[i][4]),
    );
    Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
    }
  }

}`
```

I tried getCalendarByName, getCalendarsByName, getOwnedCalendarByName`